# Razor V3 - Relative Path not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, razor, relative-path

I am using Visual Studio 2013.  I created a website (ASP.NET Web Site Razor v3) which works just fine in the browser under debug (with Chrome).  However - when I deploy the website (simple copy to IIS local), the paths for the stylesheets do not work even though they appear to be accurate in view-source.

I looked over a few threads and saw one talking about url-rewrite.  But I don't see any re-writing going on.  Maybe I am missing it.

Anyway... the styles:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/fullcalendar.css" />
```

You can see I tried a couple of options there. When I look at the source code, I see the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/MyMeds/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/fullcalendar.css" />
```

My IIS Website is in the /MyMeds/ folder.  So that would appear correct.  It is almost like it IS re-writing it.  But I do not see any re-write rules in the web.config file.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@Url.Content()`. LIke this:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/css/bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: I've tried that, but it doesn't like it.  Doesn't recognize @Url.  Do I have to import a class or namespace?

Comment: @Andrew That's a bigger problem. Probably your web.config does not have all the required directives. Do you have `<add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />` in your web.config?

Comment: No - I only have the dependent assemblies that VS2013 put into the project when creating (i.e., System.Web.Helpers, System.Web.WebPages).  I will add that one now and see what happens

Comment: I used Nuget to update. It created the assembly.  Still doesn't recognize @Url {is not declared... It may be inaccessible to due it's protection level}.